# Playing audio files packed in zip-File

Tags: java, zip, vlcj, audio-player

I try to play wav files stored in zip-Files in the filesystem with vlcj.
I tried to start the media with this call:

```
audioMediaPlayer.playMedia("jar:file:/C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav);
```

This didn't work.

```
[0000000000454750] core input error: open of `jar:file://C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav' failed
[0000000000454750] core input error: Ihre Eingabe konnte nicht ge�ffnet werden
[0000000000454750] core input error: VLC kann die Medienadresse 'jar:file://C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav' nicht �ffnen. F�r Details bitte im Fehlerprotokoll nachsehen.
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551522/vlcj-playing-a-video-from-the-res-folder-works-great-in-eclipse-but-not-fro) and tried the following

```
audioMediaPlayer.playMedia("zip://C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav);
```

this results in this errors:

```
[00000000003df990] core access error: no suitable access module for `C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip'
[00000000003df990] zip access error: not a valid zip archive: 'C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip'
[0000000000444750] core input error: open of `zip://C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav' failed
[0000000000444750] core input error: Ihre Eingabe konnte nicht ge�ffnet werden
[0000000000444750] core input error: VLC kann die Medienadresse 'zip://C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav' nicht �ffnen. F�r Details bitte im Fehlerprotokoll nachsehen.
```

What's wrong? Where did I find the error protocol?
Thankyou for your help.

Comment: I read the wav from the zip in another place and it works fine. I tried it from commandline and got also an error "Ihre Eingabe konnte nicht geöffnet werden:
VLC kann die Medienadresse 'zip://C://Users/abc/Desktop/test/28.zip!/28.wav' nicht öffnen. Für Details bitte im Fehlerprotokoll nachsehen." but no erormessage that the zip is invalid.

Comment: I just used the same path variable as for the other purposes. So I changed the slashes to backslashes. VLC seems to be more restrictive with that. The unzipped wav can be opened after that change, but the wav in the zip I still cannot access :(. Similar errors as above. To much for a comment.

Comment: VLC says: Einlesen der Datei fehlgeschlagen:
VLC konnte die Datei „\\C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\28.zip“ nicht öffnen (Bad file descriptor).
Ihre Eingabe konnte nicht geöffnet werden:
VLC kann die Medienadresse 'zip://C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\28.zip!/28.wav' nicht öffnen. Für Details bitte im Fehlerprotokoll nachsehen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
zip:///C:/test.zip!/test.avi
```

Comment: Yes it works for me! Thank you very much for your effort caprica.