# Playing videos works fine in Eclipse but when exporting the java project as an runnable JAR file it doesnt work anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, vlcj

I wrote some code which plays some .mp4 videos inside a JFrame. I am using vlcj-3.0.1 and inside eclipse everything works perfectly.
But when i am exporting the Java project as an runnable JAR file and putting the res folder seperatly in the same directory as the JAR file, the videos arent played anymore. I must been doing something wrong with the filepath, but i don't know what i am doing wrong.

I already looked up google and found a thread with the exact same problem:

[VLCJ - playing a video from the "res" folder works great in eclipse, but not from the executable JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551522/vlcj-playing-a-video-from-the-res-folder-works-great-in-eclipse-but-not-fro)

i tried using the recommendations from caprica but i had no success.

```
    // Attributes
Canvas c = new Canvas();
MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
String mrl = new File("res/video/beach.mp4").getAbsolutePath();

// For Seeing the FilePath, so i can place the res folder correctly after 
//creating the runnable jar file
System.out.println(mrl);



// Giving the Libary for VLCJ Plugin
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "lib");
Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

// Setting up the player, didnt including the jframe here, since its working
emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));
emp.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
emp.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);
emp.prepareMedia(mrl);
emp.setRepeat(true);
emp.play();
```

I expected that a JFrame opens up and plays the video on a loop.The JFrame pops up but i have just a black screen...(i set my jframe background color to black).

Comment: not a full answer so i'll just comment: You are trying to play a resource that is inside your jar file using a local file name or a file URL. This simply will not work.
You should probably extract your media from the jar file to a temporary directory (or wherever you want) and play it from there.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for replying. that was exactly the problem.

like you already mentioned, i extracted the resources to a seperate folder and let the runnable JAR file reach to the "outside" media.
it worked by an solution caprica mentioned in the other thread:

```
String mrl = new File("res/media/video.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
```

now things get a little bit different. since i wanted to load the resources from the locations where the jar file is saved (so the jar file dynamically adapts to the location of itself and the added resources.

i added the following lines:

```
String jarDir = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()).getAbsolutePath();
String dir = jarDir;
String path = "res/video/beach.mp4"

mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
emp.prepareMedia(dir + path);
emp.setRepeat(true);
emp.play();
```

Comment: A minor unrelated point, you don't need to do prepare and play separately, for your code fragment above i would just have done emp.setRepeat(true) once after you the create media player, then emp.playMedia(dir+path) rather than having prepare and play separate. prepare is only useful if you do not intend to play the media immediately.